# Different character set in different IDE for MySql DB

Tags: java, php, mysql, mysql-workbench, sequelpro

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `cs_menuitem` (
  `menuitemid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`menuitemid`),
  KEY `fi0` (`catid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=651879 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci COMMENT='InnoDB free: 9216 kB; (catid) REFER cruzstar_v01/cs_menucate';
```

Inserted UTF-8 chars using PHP

```
INSERT INTO `cs_menuitem` (`catid`, `itemname`)
VALUES
    (97260, 'as “Sautéed Pastrami” , “Piña Colada Virgin” or “Piña Colada”');
```

Select query:

```
SELECT itemname FROM cs_menuitem where menuitemid = 651841;
```

with the command line, and PHP : (correct result)

```
as “Sautéed Pastrami” , “Piña Colada Virgin” or “Piña Colada”
```

But with others (MysqlWorkbench, SequelPro, PhpMyAdmin, PhpStorm, Java), getting: (incorrect result)

```
as â€œSautÃ©ed Pastramiâ€ , â€œPiÃ±a Colada Virginâ€ or â€œPiÃ±a Coladaâ€
```

Comment: Do other apps have charset option for connections?

Comment: In none of the app is set charset, neither the language nor the Sql IDE. Only it's available inside the DB structure

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored